# How to reverse CSS animation without use 50% checkpoint

Tags: css, css-animations

I spend my time to write my animation which contains a reverse effect, with a 50% checkpoint like this:

```
element:hover {
animation: XXXX 0.5s ease-in-out 0s 1;
@keyframes XXXX {
    from {
        letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    }
    50% {
      letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
    }
    to {
      letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    }
}
```

I think it's not elegant, I would like to be able to use a css-property to declare a reverse effect. Like this for example:

```
element:hover {
animation: XXX 0.5s ease-in-out 0s 1 reverse;
@keyframes XXX {
    from {
        letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    }
    to {
        letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
    }
}
```

I've search a solution but I haven't found anything. Do you have a clearer/most beautiful solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alternate` and define only 2 iterations:

```css
.box:hover {
  animation: XXX 0.5s ease-in-out alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}

@keyframes XXX {
  from {
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  }
  to {
    letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Some text here</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is probably `animation-direction: alternate-reverse;`:

> The animation reverses direction each cycle, with the first iteration being played backwards.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

```css
@keyframes XXX {
  from {
    letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  }
  to {
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  }
}

.box:hover {
  animation: XXX 0.5s ease-in-out 0s 2 alternate-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Some text here</div>
```

Comment: you may notice that you reverted the initial animation ... so at the end we only need alternate like I suggested in my answer and we keep the initial animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, the difference between `alternate` and `alternate-reverse` is only visible for more than two iterations and based on the notation order of the animation.

Comment: no, you will have exactly the same animation :) ... you have reverted the animation so alternate on the initial animation is the same as alternate-reverse on the reverted animaion:   https://jsfiddle.net/e0mo43cn/1/

Comment: Thanks for your proposal !